Getting the Double Field Theory action from the projectors
I am mainly focusing on the following paper by Olaf Hohm and Barton Zwiebach: On the Riemann Tensor in Double Field Theory, so I'll give broad brushstrokes as to what my qualms are.
The DFT (Double Field Theory) action can be written as:
$$ S = \int dx d\tilde{x} e^{-2d} \mathcal{R}(\mathcal{H}, d),$$
where $\mathcal{H}$ and $d$ denote the generalized metric and dilaton respectively. The form of $\mathcal{R}$ can be, following the construction of the paper, written as:
$$ \mathcal{R} = P^{MK} P^{NL} \mathcal{R}_{MNKL},$$
where $ P^{MN} = \frac{1}{2} (\eta^{MN}-H^{MN})$ are the DFT projectors. $\mathcal{R}_{MNKL}$ inherits the symmetries of the Riemann tensor and can be written as:
$$ \mathcal{R}_{MNKL} = R_{MNKL} + R_{KLMN} + \Gamma^{Q}_{MN}\Gamma_{QKL}, $$
where
$$\Gamma_{M N K} = \frac12 H_{K Q}\partial_{M}{H^{Q}_{N}} + \frac14(\eta^{P}_{N}H^{Q}_{K} - \eta^{P}_{K}H^{Q}_{N} + H^{P}_{N}\eta^{Q}_{K} - H^{P}_{K}\eta^{Q}_{N})\partial_{P}{H_{Q M}} + \frac{1}{D-1}(\eta_{M N}\eta^{Q}_{K} - \eta_{M K}\eta^{Q}_{N} + H_{M N}H^{Q}_{K} - H_{M K}H^{Q}_{N})(\partial_{Q}{d} + \frac14 H^{P R}\partial_{R}{H_{P Q}}). $$
The Riemann from above can also be expressed via $\Gamma_{MNK}$, namely
$$ R_{MNKL}=\partial_{M}\Gamma_{NKL} - \partial_{N}\Gamma_{MKL} + \Gamma_{MQ}^{L}\Gamma^{NKQ} - \Gamma_{N Q}^{L}\Gamma_{M K}^{Q} .$$
In other words, the scalar curvature $\mathcal{R}$ can be written in terms of the generalized metric $\mathcal{H}$. The expected form of the scalar curvature is given by:
$$ \mathcal{R} = \frac18 \mathcal{H}^{MN}\partial_{M}\mathcal{H}^{KL}\partial_{N}\mathcal{H}_{KL} - \frac12 \mathcal{H}^{MN}\partial_{N}\mathcal{H}^{KL}\partial_{L}\mathcal{H}_{MK} + 4\mathcal{H}^{MN}\partial_{M}\partial_{N}d + 4\partial_{M}\mathcal{H}^{MN}\partial_{N}d - 4\mathcal{H}^{MN}\partial_{M}d\partial_{N}d - \partial_{M}\partial_{N}H^{MN}.$$
My problem is that I have no clue how to arrive at this expression using $$\mathcal{R} = P^{MK}P^{NL} \mathcal{R}_{MNKL}.$$ Brute forcing can only get one so far, as there are literally thousands of terms generated by the full expression. I've tried invoking symmetries wherever I can, but even then, I feel like I've dug a small hole into something that should be the size of a crater. Are there some symmetries, properties or anything really that I'm missing that makes this calculation more direct or at the very least, more approachable? I've tried looking for other sources to get a more complete picture, but I've come at an impasse.
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.
